# How to set a selected value of kendo dropdown list from a controller based on a locale?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo.DropDownList that will display cultures.

When first loading the DropDown, I want to set its default, selected value to a current culture.

This is dropdown:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()      
        .Name("culture")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataTextField("DisplayText")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read =>
            {

                read.Action("PopulateCultures", "CultureSelector");

            });
        })
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.Select("onCultureChange");
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

This is where I'm populating it:

```
public ActionResult PopulateCultures()
{
    CultureModel cm = new CultureModel();

    string uCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
    List<Culture> cultures = null;
    cultures = cm.PopulateCulture();
    if (Session["SiteUICulture"] != null) uCulture = Session["SiteUICulture"].ToString();
    try
    {
       //Here I need to set default/selected value to  a culture 
       cultures = cm.PopulateCulture();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return Json(cultures, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The Model:

public class CultureModel
{
    public string CurrentName { get; set; }

```
public List<Culture> AvailableCultures { get; set; }
public List<Culture> PopulateCulture()
{
    ClientServer iClient = new ClientServer();
    AvailableCultures = iClient.GetCultures(applicationName).ToList();

    return AvailableCultures;
}
```

}

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:-

1. The model bound to your view should have a property for the selected culture value. You can alternatively use ViewBag if you do not want to add a property to your Model.
2. The controller action corresponding to the view, should assign this a value to this property.
3. On the view set this model value to the drop down list

For Example: 
Available Cultures bound to your dropdown are:- 
[{ Id=1, Name=English-US}, { Id=2, Name=English-UK}]

If the name of the property you added is SelectedCulture
Your controller would set it to an available value like SelectedCulture = 1

Your view would set the value in the dropdown

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()      
        .Name("culture")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataTextField("DisplayText")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read =>
            {

                read.Action("PopulateCultures", "CultureSelector");

            });
        })
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.Select("onCultureChange");
        })
        .Value(Model.SelectedCulture)
);
```